# What is -[UITableViewDelegate willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] for?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In all of my `UITableView` programming, I've always configured my `UITableViewCells` in -`[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`. Now I've come across the -`[UITableViewDelegate willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]` method. That also seems like an appropriate place to do cell configuration.

My question is: what's the appropriate "division of labor" between these two methods? What should I do in one vs. the other?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You use that to configure things like font and text color. In the newer version of the iPhone, with certain table configurations, if you configure things like the label text color in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, your changes will be lost at some point before the cell is actually displayed. Here you can do things like change the label's color, adjust background highlighting, such things as these.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a rationale for why changes to cells made in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: might get "lost"? I'm wondering where that boundary is between things that get lost and things that won't.

Comment: None that I know of. I didn't even know that this existed either until suddenly a bunch of label changes stopped working when we built for the 3.0 SDK (and even then, only in very specific table configurations). When we bugged this, we got back "works as intended: use willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: for this. No other explanation was ever provided ;)

Comment: Actually, thinking more on it, you are probably supposed to do display-related things here and content related/cell initialization things in the other.

Comment: What I'm thinking: why not just put cell creation/dequeueing in cellForRowAtIndexPath, then everything else in willDisplayCell:? I simply haven't run into any problems doing it the old-fashioned way, but I may shift to this model in the future.

Comment: One thing that definitely fails unless done in willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: is the backgroundColor property on either the textLabel or the detailedTextLabel. If you set those in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, the property will be reset to the tableView's background color before actually being displayed (but even then, only in standard table views).

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but it makes complete sense to keep view-related details out of the data source delegate... that's why it's a separate delegate! Let it worry about your model, let the view delegate worry about the view. As your app scales up, you ideally want to be left well positioned to externalize the data source delegate to a new class (and if you have the habit of intermingling it, it might be best to separate them from the start).

Comment: I ran into an issue once where I am applying rotation transform to the cell in `willDisplayCell`. If I add new cells quickly (in simulator, by clicking really fast), sometimes the cell gets mis-positioned for some reason. When I move the transform into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the whole thing works as expected. Weird...

Comment: I had trouble with an NSAttributedString being applied to an attributed UILabel in a cell. I set the attributed text of the label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the attributes would get lost somehow before drawing the cell. When I moved this assignment over to `willDisplayCell` it finally worked. Many hours lost trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. I wish this behavior was better explained or warned of in documentation.