# UITableViewCell Font Not Changing

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to customize the font of a `UITableViewCell` using the following code for when the tableview is populated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell  
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];   
    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = temp;
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:154.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];  

    return cell;
}
```

For the life of me  I don't know why it won't change the font! Also the above code works fine if I hard code in what the cell text is such as `cell.textLabel.text = @"TEST";`

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, you should autorelease your cell. You are leaking memory like crazy presently.

Second, you should update the font in `tableView:willDisplayCellForRow:atIndexPath:`. If you are using a standard table view, it will make changes to your cells (at random times) and you will need to do things like font changes, background color, etc in the `tableView:willDisplayCellForRow:atIndexPath:` instead of in the data source method.

See also this thread: [What is -[UITableViewDelegate willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890265/what-is-uitableviewdelegate-willdisplaycellforrowatindexpath-for)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the methods where I should change it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

@Jason Coco:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just you can try with following code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellString = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellString];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellString];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = values;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:154.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: try to use cell.textLabel.font or cell.detailTextLabel.font

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: can be used for modifying the cell's background color, content view, etc, except the backgroundColor property of textlabel and detailtextlabel

Its always a good practice to do these modifications in the above method

Answer (score -2):

very simple, `

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor]; //redColor greenColor etc.
}
```