# UITableViewCell shows mixed fonts

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

For some reason, my UITableViewCell is showing a mixture of fonts.  Here's a screenshot that demonstrates what I mean:

[image: Mixed fonts on a single UITableViewCell]

Note the last number in each row is the wrong font.  Based on my testing, it's somewhat random which character(s) get messed up, so don't let the fact that it's the last characters in this screenshot throw you off.

Here's my code for setting the fonts:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImageView *iv;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [[cell textLabel] setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"BangBang" size: 36.0]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"BangBang" size: 32.0]];
        iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"woodTableRow~ipad.png"]];
    } else {        
        [[cell textLabel] setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"BangBang" size: 22.0]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"BangBang" size: 22.0]];
        iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"woodTableRow.png"]];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundView: iv];
    [iv release];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [[cell textLabel] setShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[cell textLabel] setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case ScoreRow:
            [[cell textLabel] setText: @"Score"];
            [[cell detailTextLabel] setText: @"1,234"];
            break;
        case TimeRow:
            [[cell textLabel] setText: @"Time"];
            [[cell detailTextLabel] setText: @"0:39"];
            break;
        default:
            [[cell textLabel] setText: @""];
            [[cell detailTextLabel] setText: @""];
            break;
    }
}
```

This makes no sense to me.  Can anyone help?

**Update:**

I should note that I've looked at these two StackOverFlow questions, but neither helped:

[UITableViewCell Font Not Changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895425/uitableviewcell-font-not-changing)

[What is -[UITableViewDelegate willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:] for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890265/what-is-uitableviewdelegate-willdisplaycellforrowatindexpath-for)

Comment: Is it always the same characters?  i.e. 4's and 9's?

Comment: Oh for goodness sakes!  That's it.  The font is incomplete.  It has glyphs for 0, 1, 2 and 3, but no more.   Arrrggghhhh!  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks good, so I would suspect that it is an incomplete font implementation.