# Xcode interface builder: Static table view cell font is not being set

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I am trying to set the font of static table view cells, using Interface Builder. I added all the cells visually using interface builder. Now I want to change the font of the table view cells.

First, I tried selecting the label of each cell and changing it to attributed text, and I set the font. Even the preview is showing the correct font, but the simulator still shows the normal font.

Then I kept it as a plain label, but changed the font from there. Still, the Interface Builder shows the correct font. But the results show otherwise.

So what do I do? It'll be a hassle to create an array, create a bunch of segues, and use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. Maybe there's a better way? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use following method **willDisplayCell** to set custom fonts of the table cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
}
```

because your changes will be lost when the cell is actually displayed using xib file or using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

follow this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890265/what-is-uitableviewdelegate-willdisplaycellforrowatindexpath-for) and [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895425/uitableviewcell-font-not-changing)