# Background color of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using a basic table view cell, set up in IB.  The only customization I apply is in cellForRowAtIndexPath, where I simply set the background color of the cell's label (**not** the color of the cell itself).

```
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

When the table is first drawn, the background color is not applied.  As I scroll down, it **is** applied to new cells as they are drawn.  Similarly, if I scroll back up, the top cells are re-drawn with the correct background color.

What is the explanation behind this?

[image]
[image]

Edit - here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath, and the set up in IB:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
ItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell2"];
[[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];            
return cell;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you post all of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? Would help us pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Also, you posted the same image twice.

Comment: Thanks Eli - I have corrected this and added what you requested.

Comment: Why ItemCell instead of UITableViewCell *cell ?

Comment: ItemCell was used for some other customization.  I stripped it out for the purposes of this demo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

from the docs:

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color.

Comment: Thanks - once I searched willDisplayCell I also found this explanation useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890265/what-is-uitableviewdelegate-willdisplaycellforrowatindexpath-for