# Text in uitable row cell title that is rendering poorly in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have some text in table row cell title that is rendering poorly. I increased the font size so that it can be seen better. Also, the quality of the font changes as the table scrolls.

The font was added to the project and works fine elsewhere in the app. It's just this tableview.

This is happening on an iPad 2. the 3GS device looks fine.

Does anyone know why this might occur?

here's the code I'm adding it with:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
[cell.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 15.0f]];
```

here's a screenshot.

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid font name?

Comment: i tried with Arial and the same thing.

Comment: fyi: This is happening on an iPad 2. the 3GS device looks fine.

Comment: Can you try boldSystemFontOfSize: and find out if that looks okay?  Then we can rule out font.

Comment: Please add code line NSLog("%f; %f;", cell.titleLabel.frame.origin.x,  cell.titleLabel.frame.origin.y); and get your log output.

Comment: I may be on the wrong track here, but I don't think Asap-Bold is a valid font name, and neither is Arial (you need to use ArialMT or Arial-BoldMT)

Comment: @danh I just tried     [cell.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]]; and the same problem persists

Comment: @DizAsm the output is: 120.000000 4.000000

Comment: @Darren I added that font to the project. It's fine on the detail view that the table view moves to

Comment: Also, the quality of the font changes as the table scrolls.

Comment: stumped.  if there's a code problem, it's not in the posted code.

Comment: Are you sure you are not creating labels everytime ??? Since issue occurs when you scroll then this **might** be issue of overlapping labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code from

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

to

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

More info/discussion at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890265/what-is-uitableviewdelegate-willdisplaycellforrowatindexpath-for).